# ¿Cómo volver la identidad de un campo a 1?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene una columna con auto-incrementar (*Identity*), ¿como la vuelvo a cero?

Comment: Encontré la respuesta en StackOverflow en Ingles ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server)) <DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ]}}])
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]>

Comment: Hay varios contextos según los cuales conviene que uses uno u otro argumento. Conviene que [revises la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) y que indiques tu contexto, por ejemplo si es una tabla que acabas de limpiar borrando todos sus registros.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es una tabla en la que borré todos los datos, gracias por la intervención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el comando **[`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** en versiones de SQL Server desde 2008 en adelante.

La documentación trata tu caso en el apartado: **[D. Resetting the identity value on an empty table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-resetting-the-identity-value-on-an-empty-table)** (*Resetando el valor de indentidad de una tabla vacía*).

El comando sería:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.TuTabla', RESEED, 1);
```

Al hacer esto, el sistema forzará el valor de identidad actual en la columna auto-incremental de la tabla a un valor de 1.

Este comando conviene ejecutarlo **inmediatamente después** de haber eliminado todos los registros de la tabla mediante:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TuTabla;
```

Como la tabla no tiene filas existentes, la siguiente fila insertada usará 1 como valor, es decir, el nuevo valor de identidad actual, sin agregar el valor de incremento definido para la columna.